# Tutorial for Quick Look Generator not associated with .app

Tags: macos, file-extension, quicklook

I've checked out Apple's [Quick Look Programming Guide: Introduction to Quick Look](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) page in the Mac Dev Center, but as a more of a science programmer rather than an Apple programmer, it is a little over my head (but I could get through it in a weekend if I bash my head against it long enough).

Does anyone know of a good *basic* Quick Look Generators tutorial that is simple enough for someone with only very modest experience with Xcode?

For those that are curious, I have a filetype called `.evt` that has an xml header and then binary info after the header. I'm trying to write a generator to display the xml header. There's no application bundle that it belongs to. Thanks!

Comment: There is a question on Server Fault with links to how to make a qlgenerator: http://serverfault.com/questions/6863/how-do-i-view-csv-files-in-quicklook

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start with looking at sample code. Some people learn faster from seeing an example. Here's a generator example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/QuickLookSketch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm an example learner for sure. Have you seen examples of QLGs that are not attached to an App? For example, I rename my_friends.txt to my_friends.fnd and want to just view the file with Quick Look.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "not attached to an App". Can you explain what the problem you're having is?

Comment: To extend my other comment, lets say I have a file my_friends.fnd that lists my friends. If I quick look this, it doesn't know how to render a preview, right? There is no program associated with the ".fnd" exention (maybe a command line program or something, but not a .app bundle). How do I write a QLG for that? Most tutorials go in the direction of referencing a .app that owns the file.

Comment: QuickLook doesn't use the file's app to get a preview, it uses the generator. That's the whole point. ;) Here's a sample I found by Googling:
http://brushviewer.sourceforge.net/
It's a viewer for photoshop brush files (abr).  Might be a good example to start with.

Comment: The URL in the answer is no longer valid. [This](http://code.google.com/p/quicklook-csv/) csv project might be helpful.